# How can i obfuscate the call stack in my C program and force the compiler to not push the return address in the stack?

Tags: c, visual-studio, security, gcc, obfuscation

I want to force my generated executable file (for both Linux and Windows), to not push the return address on the stack when i call a function/API.

So what is the easiest way to achieve this? Let's assume i compile the program using GCC or Visual Studio, and i want this to happen for every call instruction. The reason i want to do this is to obfuscate my program.

**If doing this is not possible at the compiler level**, then how can i achieve the same goal?

For example what about this solution:

I replace every function/API call with a macro that takes the destination function adderss, pushes the arguments, encrypts the return address, pushes the encrypted return address, and does a jmp to the destination function address (using inline assembly ofc) therefore no call instruction is used; then before every return location in my functions, i place a macro that decrypts the pushed return address and jmps to it (again using inline assembly).

So this is the best solution, right?

```
void foo()
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    foo(); // obfuscate this in a way that it doesn't use call, or the call somehow doesn't push the return address.
}
```

Note that i only want to implement this in a way that known debuggers not be able to show the call stack, such as **Windbg**, **xdbg**, etc, and that's it. So even a simple xor encryption of return address is suffice for me (And obviously later on if needed, i can make the encryption more complex). But is there any implementation flaw in the proposed solution?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243414/discussion-on-question-by-oneandonly-how-can-i-obfuscate-the-call-stack-in-my-c).

Answer (score 3):

You can't. When you make a `call`, you need a return address, this can't be in any way modified.

Wanting to use `jmp` instead is irrelevant. That will work for function `A`. But for function `B`, the `jmp` will be invalid because it will jump back to `A` again, not to `B`.

Either you put all your code within a single, ugly, massive function (use `#define` pseudo-functions to ensure inlining), then you'll have only `jmp` inside, or you forget to trick the CPU mechanisms.

And even if you write your own compiler, you'll face the exact, same, problem: *were should you return after a function is finished, when you have multiple calling points?*

---

Obfuscation isn't a good way to protect your code, and it won't stop anybody who knows assembler - because **in the end, you must have valid and meaningful ASM instructions to do anything requested**. So it can be traced.

You can check [this page](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eaburtsev/malw-sem/slides/02-anti-debugging.pdf), or [this page](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eaburtsev/malw-sem/slides/02-anti-debugging.pdf), for **correct** antidebug techniques. But the more tricks like these you put in your code, the more chances you have to be killed instantly by any decent antivirus.

Because don't forget something: *in fine*, any hacker can replace every annoying part of your code by `nop` (`0x90h` in hexa), put the suitable value in the suitable register/memory to bypass everything, or replace any `jz`/`jnz` with an inconditional `jmp`.

If you need something quick and powerful enough to challenge a non-profesional hacker, put a dongle and encrypt your executable through the dongle SDK. Anything else is just a waste of time and, more annoying, a high risk of being detected as malware/virus/trojan.

And doing this cross-platform is even more irrelevant, since most anti-debugging techniques rely on operating system (and sometimes CPU model/revision!!) to work.

And let's admit that you managed to build a perfect antidebug code, with encrypted code and everything possible... What will you do against a [Lauterbach probe](https://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?tools_intel.html#_H1) or other similar hardware debuggers that can't even be detected by your software?
It's not everybody's tool, right, but I have several of these beauties at work, for a wide range of CPU... And I'm not the only one.

Comment: I updated the question with a proposed solution, would you mind giving it a look and maybe updating the answer based on that solution? is there is any flaw in the proposed solution?

Comment: @OneAndOnly It won't work either. I spoke about that (using macros for "inlining"), and two minutes with a debugger will break your "encryption", because I highly doubt that you could find anything suitable to encrypt/decrypt _ONLY 64 BITS_, when the strongest possible algorithm would be a XOR with a 64 bits throwable key... Constant key? Broke in two seconds. Pseudo-generated key? Broke in two minutes, since you'll probably use something like a Mersenne twister. And, again, it won't work anyway since you CPU needs these informations, and that's not software, but hardware.

Comment: But as i said, I'm not trying to stop every possible reverse engineer, obviously no matter how crazy i implement the encryption, there will be someone who breaks it, but right now even a simple xor would be enough for me, i just want known debuggers such as windbg to not be able to show the call stack and that's it, absolutely nothing else, so a simple XOR would suffice. So will my solution do that? Any implementation problem with the solution that i need to take into account?

Comment: @OneAndOnly The main question should be _WHY do you need this?_. You also don't understand that this will NOT work, since the `call` itself push the address... So by putting a BP at FIRST ASSEMBLER instruction of your subfunction, you'll have the real caller displayed in call stack. You can mess it through software after, _the caller will still be visible perfectly_. Need only to poke some `nop` on your "obfuscation", and we get a full call stack without any problem. You'll spend weeks to implement this, and it will be defeated in **MINUTES**. It doesn't worth the effort.

Comment: It seems like i explained the solution poorly, my solution replaces every call instruction with a jmp instruction (push args, push encrypted ret address, jmp), so there is no call instruction. By putting a bp inside the first instruction of a function, the encrypted ret adderss is on the stack.

Comment: @OneAndOnly A protection is worth the effort when there is several MAGNITUDES of effort between implementing the protection and trying to defeat it. If you need 2 weeks to set a protection, and if it requires two YEARS to be defeated, it's OK. If it requires "only" 4 weeks to defeat it, then it's already irrelevant to spend time on this useless "protection".
Think about [trapdoor functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function) for an idea  of the magnitude needed for a protection against its hacking.

Comment: @OneAndOnly Even in this case. The return adress is LOADED IN CLEAR INTO A REGISTER before jumping, that's exactly the SAME as trying to mask a `call`. It still won't work, because you CANNOT protect a program this way, AT ALL. Masking call stack won't protect anything, in particular when you can get it back in, I repeat, a matter of **MINUTES**.

Comment: I'm not sure i quite understand, why are you saying the return address is loaded in clear into register? I don't load it into any register and i don't use any call instruction.. I push the ENCRYPTED return address into stack. Also you have to understand that security is a step by step process, the current goal is to Stop known debuggers from showing the call stack, that's it.. making the encryption more complex is off topic right now and that's the next step which is unrelated right now.

Comment: @OneAndOnly Once compiled, at a given time, you MUST have the address, IN CLEAR, to allow the CPU to jump. Period, it's over. It cannot work without an encrypted CPU, with also encrypted RAM and encrypted mass storage. What you want to do IS NOT POSSIBLE, not with HUGE flaws that will defeat your "protection" in only a few **MINUTES**. Read again: I would have defeated your "protection" IN LESS TIME THAT I USED TO WRITE THIS ANSWER AND COMMENTS. Do you realize that? For real? And you still want to put weeks of work to make this anyway?